# Infinite while loop with break condition in SQR

Tags: loops, sqr

I have this infinite loop problem in a sqr code. I have a condition that should stop it though and a the $objet is equal [4]:
Here is the code:

begin-procedure Extracteur(#id_document)

move -1 to #index_fin_objet
   do Lire_ligne_suivante($objet)
   do Lire_ligne_suivante($ligne)

let #occurrence = 1
   if $ligne = 'FIN'
      do Extr_objet($objet,0,#index_fin_objet,0,#occurrence,0)
   end-if

while $ligne <> 'FIN'

```
  if $objet <> 'FIN'

     get #num_lettre from DOCUMENT(0) num_derniere_lettre
     get #nb_occurrences from BOITE_AUX_LETTRES(#num_lettre) occurrence
     let #compteur_occurrence = 1 
     let #occurrence = 1
     print #nb_occurrences (+1,1)
     while (#compteur_occurrence <= #nb_occurrences)
        let #index_deb_objet = #index_fin_objet + 1

          print $objet (+1,1)
          print #occurrence (,+5)
          print #num_lettre (,+5)
          print #compteur_occurrence (,+5)
        if $ligne = '{' 
          do Extr_objet($objet,#index_deb_objet,#index_fin_objet,1,
                        #occurrence,#num_lettre)
        else
          do Extr_objet($objet,#index_deb_objet,#index_fin_objet,0,
                        #occurrence,#num_lettre)
        end-if

        add 1 to #compteur_occurrence  
        subtract 1 from #num_lettre 
     end-while
  end-if

  evaluate $ligne
     when = '{'
        let $objet = '' 
        break
     when = '}'
        let $objet = '' 
        do Depiler_BOITE_AUX_LETTRES
        break
     when-other
        let $objet = $ligne
  end-evaluate

  do Lire_ligne_suivante($ligne)

  **IF $objet = '[4]'
    print 'objet 4' (+1,1)
    print $objet    (+1,1)
    break;
  end-if**

  if $ligne = 'FIN'
     let #index_deb_objet = #index_fin_objet + 1
     let #occurrence = 0
     do Extr_objet($objet,#index_deb_objet,#index_fin_objet,0,#occurrence,0)
  end-if
```

end-while

end-procedure

and here is the Lire_ligne_suivante procedure :
begin-procedure Lire_ligne_suivante(:$ligne)

get #num_fichier_cpl from DOCUMENT(0) num_fichier_document
read #num_fichier_cpl into $ligne:30
if #end-file
   move 'FIN' to $ligne
else
  if $ligne = '[1]' 
    read #num_fichier_cpl into $ligne:30
   end-if

if $ligne = '[2]'
      let $ligne = 'FIN'
   end-if
end-if

end-procedure

Thank you!

Comment: At some point I print $objet and it shows [4].

Comment: Can you show the output? Are you sure you dont have any other characters in the [4], such as an extra space at the end?